# "TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable", when trying to select something from dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get the following error when trying to do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\seal\doc\main\main.py", line 172, in <module>
    select()
  File "c:\Users\seal\doc\main\main.py", line 108, in select
    drop = driver(By.ID, 'fulfillment_duration')
TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
drop = driver(By.ID, 'fulfillment_duration') 
drop.select_by_value("one_day")
```

How would I fix this and how would I select something from a dropdown?

Here is the element:

```
<select aria-invalid="false" id="fulfillment_duration" name="fulfillment_duration" class="Select-element PressableContext Padding-right--24 Padding-left--8 Padding-vertical--4 PressableContext--cursor--pointer PressableContext--display--inlineFlex PressableContext--fontLineHeight--20 PressableContext--fontSize--14 PressableContext--fontWeight--medium PressableContext--height PressableContext--height--medium PressableContext--radius--all PressableContext--width PressableContext--width--auto" style="color: rgb(64, 68, 82);"><option disabled="" value="">Please select…</option><option value="one_day">Within one day</option><option value="two_weeks">Within 2 weeks</option><option value="one_month">Within one month</option><option value="months">More than one month</option></select>
```

I would like it to select the option "one_day"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the entire `code` ? Where is `Webdriver` ?

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `drop = driver(By.ID, 'fulfillment_duration')`
Try

```py
drop = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'fulfillment_duration')
```

Also, you probably will need to introduce a delay here, so the better code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

drop = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fulfillment_duration')))
```